# Convert column of lists to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I'm doing some operations on a Pandas dataframe. For a certain column, I need to convert each cell to a numpy array which is not hard. The end goal is to get a 2D array as a result from the whole column. However, when I perform the following operation, I got a 1D array, and the inner arrays are not recognized.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['abc', 'def']})
mapping = {v: k for k, v in enumerate('abcdef')}
df['new'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
df['new'].apply(lambda x: np.array([mapping[i] for i in x])).values
```

This gives:

```
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

and the shape is (2,), meaning the inner arrays are not recognized.

If I do `s.reshape(2,-1)`, I got `(2,1)` instead of `(2,3)` for the shape.

Appreciate any help!

---

Clarification:

The above is only a toy example. What I was doing was preprocessing for machine learning using the IMDB dataset. I had to convert each value in a review column to a word embedding which is a numpy array. Now the challenge is to get all these arrays out as a 2D array, so that I can use them in my machine learning model.

Comment: `np.array(df['new'].values.tolist())` or `np.stack(df['new'])`

Comment: @user3483203 `tolist()` will mean it's no longer an array

Comment: @roganjosh not sure what you mean.  If you leave out the `tolist`, you will get an array of type object with a shape of `(2,)`

Comment: @user3483203 but still a numpy array, that you can try (if in a suitable state) to convert the type of. `tolist()` drops it out to a python list, which you're just going to convert back to an array? You could just leave it at `.values`? Or am I missing something

Comment: @George are you looking for a nested array within a pandas cell?

Comment: He is expecting an array of shape `(2, 3)`.  If you just call `df['new'].values`, you get a 1D array containing two python lists.

Comment: I don't see why you can't simply use `s = np.array(df['new'].apply(lambda x: np.array([mapping[i] for i in x])).values.tolist())`. Just convert to list and then to numpy array. Now, `s.shape` gives `(2,3)`

Comment: Yes, I was expecting an array of shape (2,3).

Comment: @GeorgeLiu is your mapping always letter -> number?  You shouldn't need to loop for that, you can vectorize it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it would be better to create an array from the list values directly.

```
 df
   col        new
0  abc  [a, b, c]
1  def  [d, e, f]

arr = np.array(df['new'].tolist())
arr
# array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
#        ['d', 'e', 'f']], dtype='<U1')

arr.shape
# (2, 3)
```

**Big disclaimer:** This will work only if the sublists all have the same number of elements. If not, it will mean they are ragged arrays, and numpy will not be able to use an efficient memory format for representing your array (hence, the `dtype='object'`).

Comment: `concatenate` (or one its `stack` daughters) will treat a 1d object array as a list, and attempt to join the subarrays into one.

Comment: @hpaulj I'guessing it would be a lot slower though, since `concatenate` is working with an object array, right?

Comment: We need to do some timings :)

Comment: @hpaulj Does `np.stack(df[['new']].values, axis=1)` give you a 2D array of shape (2,3)? It doesn't seem to work, they remain lists for me.

Comment: `axis=0` is the version that replicates `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['abc', 'def']})
   ...: mapping = {v: k for k, v in enumerate('abcdef')}
   ...: df['new'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: list(x))

In [7]: df['new']
Out[7]: 
0    [a, b, c]
1    [d, e, f]
Name: new, dtype: object
In [8]: df['new'].values
Out[8]: array([list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['d', 'e', 'f'])], dtype=object)
```

`np.stack` behaves a lot like `np.array`, joining the elements on a new initial axis:

```
In [9]: np.stack(df['new'].values)
Out[9]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
```

or on another axis you your choice:

```
In [10]: np.stack(df['new'].values, axis=1)
Out[10]: 
array([['a', 'd'],
       ['b', 'e'],
       ['c', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
```

`np.array` also works if the object array is turned into a list (as @coldspeed shows):

```
In [11]: df['new'].values.tolist()
Out[11]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
In [12]: np.array(df['new'].values.tolist())
Out[12]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
```

As for speed, lets make a bigger array:

```
In [16]: arr = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: np.arange(1000),1,1)(np.arange(1000))
In [17]: arr.shape
Out[17]: (1000,)
In [18]: np.stack(arr).shape
Out[18]: (1000, 1000)
In [20]: np.array(arr.tolist()).shape
Out[20]: (1000, 1000)

In [21]: timeit np.stack(arr).shape
5.24 ms ± 190 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [22]: timeit np.array(arr.tolist()).shape
4.45 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Basically the same, with a slight edge to the `np.array` approach.

`stack` like `vstack` expands the dimensions of each element as needed.  Skipping that with a `concatenate` is a bit faster:

```
In [27]: timeit np.concatenate(arr).reshape(-1,1000).shape
4.04 ms ± 12.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This `arr` contains arrays.  If it contained lists instead the `array(arr.tolist())` approach does better (relatively), since it has only one list (of lists) to convert to array. The `stack` approach has to first convert each of the sublists into arrays.